# Awaiting parameters before the test is run

Tags: async-await, playwright

I am trying to parameterize my tests.
Normally you can do that pretty easily with something like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
//Test
}
```

However, I am getting my parameters through an api request, and want to run the tests based on the amount of received paramters.

I have an async function that makes the api request to get the parameters:

```
const getParams = new Params();
const par = getParams.fetchTestCaseParameters();
```

And then I want to run it like:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < par.length; i++){
    //Test
    }
```

The problem is my code wont wait for par to resolve to anything, so the above loop just exists and it can't find my tests.

Putting the fetchParamters function inside test.BeforeAll() doesn't work either, cause it doesn't enter the before all until it gets to the test itself, which is inside my loop.

This is my beforeEach now:

```
test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
  const getParams = new Params();
  par = await getParams.fetchTestCaseParameters('');
});
```

And the loop for accessing the test:

```
for(let i = 0; i < par.length; i++){
    test(`Create company`, async ({ page }) => {
        test.step('some step', async () => {
            //test code
}}
```

My api function looks like this:

```
export class Params{
  async fetchTestCaseParameters(testCaseId) {
    try {
      const url = ``;
      const headers = {
        Authorization: `Basic ${encodedToken}`,
      };
      const response = await axios.get(url, { headers });
      const xmlData = response.data.fields['Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.LocalDataSource'];
      let parsedData;
      parseString(xmlData, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
        parsedData = result;
      });
      return parsedData.NewDataSet.Table1;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error retrieving test case parameters:', error.message);
      throw error;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Please share the full relevant CODE in minimal re producible code example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example format so that someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your API can return same data (not random on every request) you can archive it with `sync-fetch` because top async is not allowed.

```js
import { test } from "@playwright/test";
import _fetch from "sync-fetch";

const json = _fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments").json();
for (const data of json) {
  test(`Data: ${data.email}`, async () => {
    console.log(data.email);
  });
}
```

```bash
Running 5 tests using 1 worker


  ✓  1 platforms\x.spec.ts:6:7 › Data: Eliseo@gardner.biz (31ms)                                                                                  
Eliseo@gardner.biz
  ✓  2 platforms\x.spec.ts:6:7 › Data: Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com (11ms)                                                                              
Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com
  ✓  3 platforms\x.spec.ts:6:7 › Data: Nikita@garfield.biz (8ms)                                                                                  
Nikita@garfield.biz
  ✓  4 platforms\x.spec.ts:6:7 › Data: Lew@alysha.tv (11ms)                                                                                       
Lew@alysha.tv
  ✓  5 platforms\x.spec.ts:6:7 › Data: Hayden@althea.biz (18ms)
Hayden@althea.biz
```

Otherwise, it's better to use `test.step` and before functions to generate data.

Comment: I want to use test.BeforeEach ideally, but then it wont enter the loop.

If i have something like this:

`test.BeforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
par = await getParams.fetchTestCaseParameters();
}`

and then use the loop before my test:

`for (let i = 0; i > par.length; i++){
test('create company', async ({ page }) => {

await test.step ('some step', async () => {
//test code
}
}`

It never enters my test.BeforeEach, because the par.length isn't resolved so it cant enter the for loop

Comment: You can't use beforeEach to generate test parameters. See https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/24273#issuecomment-1640003150